# im trying to write something in a seeker with pyautogui, but it does not write anything were it has to

Tags: python, pyautogui

im trying to make a loop and write lines of a text file on a seeker and i would like to loop across the lines of the text file, but every time i run the script pyatogui dosen´t write anything.

This is de code:

```
contactos = open("contactos.txt")

for line in contactos:
    time.sleep(5)

    pyautogui.click(x=100, y=150)
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.write(str(line))
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not actually reading anything from the file.

Try this:

```
contactos = open("contactos.txt")
lines = contactos.readlines()

for line in lines:
    ...
```